# Rearranging the matrix column accordance to characteristics C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, matrix

My task sounds like: The characteristic of a column of an integer matrix is the sum of its negative odd elements. Rearranging the columns of a given matrix, arrange them in accordance with the growth of characteristics.

I am make two subarrays. In first which is called "nesort" i see not sorted characteristics of  array . In other which is called "tab" i see sorted according my task. Then i comparing the subarrays by the elements and generate new one. But the trouble is when in generated on start array be a replay of number. The final array gonna be bigger than we need. Can you please help me and watch my code. Especially my loops. What's the problem?

```
There is example of my code :
enter code here 




#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    cout << "Практическая работа по практике Казаков 9903:" << endl;

    const int ROWS = 5;
    const int COLS = 5;

    int arr[ROWS][COLS];
    int nesort[COLS];
    int tab[COLS];


    //Array generating
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 41 - 20;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Массив построен!" << endl << "\n";

    //Counting and output of characteristics
    cout << "Суммы нечётных, отрицательных элементов столбцов: " << endl;


    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] < 0 && arr[i][j] & 1)
            {
                sum = sum + arr[i][j];
            }

        }
        nesort[j] = sum;
        tab[j] = sum;
    }



    for (int s = 0; s < COLS; s++)
    {
        cout << nesort[s] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    //Sorting of columns characteristics
    cout << "Отсортированные характеристики столбцов: " << endl;

    int n = sizeof(tab) / sizeof(tab[0]);
    sort(tab, tab + n);


    for (int r = 0; r < COLS; r++)
    {
        cout << tab[r] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Отсортированный по хар-кам массив: " << endl;

    //Sorting the start array by characteristics

    for (int n = 0; n < ROWS; n++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            if (tab[n] == nesort[i])
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
                {
                    cout << arr[j][i] << "\n";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `std::ranges::sort(tab);`

Comment: I assume `for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)` should be `for (int n = 0; n < ROWS; n++)`?

Comment: Could your problem be that you have multiple columns with the same caracteristic so your `if (tab[n] == nesort[i])` matches multiple times? And why are you sorting rows by the characteristic of columns?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow  
for (int n = 0; n < ROWS; n++)- Yeah i change this. 
std::ranges::sort(tab); - For what i need this command? I am already have sorted array calls "tab"  And knowing that i need sort starting array by characteristics that i have in array "tabs" accordance with the growth of characteristics.

Yeah problem is if we have multiple same numbers loop work incorrect. And if you can help how i need sort this array not by characteristics of other array i will be glad to hear it

Comment: `std::ranges::sort(tab);` in place of `sort(tab, tab + n);`

Comment: If you want to sort rows by the sum of their columns you can use a projection in sort, something like: `std::ranges::sort(tab, std::less(), [](row){return std::accumulate(&row[0], &row[COLS - 1], 0); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in the last loops. This can be easily be fixed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    cout << "Практическая работа по практике Казаков 9903:" << endl;

    const int ROWS = 5;
    const int COLS = 5;

    int arr[ROWS][COLS];
    int nesort[COLS];
    int tab[COLS];


    //Array generating
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 41 - 20;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Массив построен!" << endl << "\n";

    //Counting and output of characteristics
    cout << "Суммы нечётных, отрицательных элементов столбцов: " << endl;


    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] < 0 && arr[i][j] & 1)
            {
                sum = sum + arr[i][j];
            }

        }
        nesort[j] = sum;
        tab[j] = sum;
    }



    for (int s = 0; s < COLS; s++)
    {
        cout << nesort[s] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    //Sorting of columns characteristics
    cout << "Отсортированные характеристики столбцов: " << endl;

    int n = sizeof(tab) / sizeof(tab[0]);
    sort(tab, tab + n);


    for (int r = 0; r < COLS; r++)
    {
        cout << tab[r] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Отсортированный по хар-кам массив: " << endl;

    //Sorting the start array by characteristics

    for (int sortedColSumIndex = 0; sortedColSumIndex < COLS; ++sortedColSumIndex) {
        for (int colSumIndex = 0; colSumIndex < COLS; ++colSumIndex) {
            if (tab[sortedColSumIndex] == nesort[colSumIndex]) {
                for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row) {
                    std::cout << arr[row][colSumIndex] << '\n';
                }
                std::cout << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this iwll not help the major design problem that the columns will apper multiple times, if the sums of the comums are double or multiple.

That cannot be healed that easily.

A change in design would be necessary. You need to sort accoring to the column **index**.

So, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    cout << "Практическая работа по практике Казаков 9903:" << endl;

    const int ROWS = 5;
    const int COLS = 5;

    int arr[ROWS][COLS];
    int nesort[COLS];
    int tab[COLS];


    //Array generating
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 41 - 20;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Массив построен!" << endl << "\n";

    //Counting and output of characteristics
    cout << "Суммы нечётных, отрицательных элементов столбцов: " << endl;


    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] < 0 && arr[i][j] & 1)
            {
                sum = sum + arr[i][j];
            }

        }
        nesort[j] = sum;
        tab[j] = j;
    }

    for (int s = 0; s < COLS; s++)
    {
        cout << nesort[s] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    //Sorting of columns characteristics
    cout << "Отсортированные характеристики столбцов: " << endl;

    int n = sizeof(tab) / sizeof(tab[0]);
    sort(tab, tab + n, [&](const int i1, const int i2) {return nesort[i1] < nesort[i2]; });


    for (int r = 0; r < COLS; r++)
    {
        cout << tab[r] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Отсортированный по хар-кам массив: " << endl;

    //Sorting the start array by characteristics
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row) {
        for (int sortedColSumIndex = 0; sortedColSumIndex < COLS; ++sortedColSumIndex) {
            std::cout << arr[row][tab[sortedColSumIndex]] << '\t';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: I tryna use this cod. At the string number 74 where sort(tab,tab+n,&{return nesort[i1]< nesort[i2]; }); appear the issue like expected an expression.

Comment: Please use a compiler that understands C++17 code. Please set the respective compiler flags.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2019 how i can do that? Or What complier i can use?!

Comment: Goto Project->Properties->c/c++/Language/C++ Language Standard then select ISO C++17

Comment: i switched language standart on ISO C++17, but the issue dont resolved. Still appear the message in str №74. Like "expected an expression"(

Comment: Thanks to Armin Montigny for his decision he is was the answer of issue